# Simplifying a solution to $x^2 = 4 + 2\sqrt{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$$x^2 = 4 + 2\sqrt{2}$$

$$x = 2 + \sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Neglecting that the result can be negative as well, how should I continue? How can I simplify it?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt {a+b}\neq \sqrt a +\sqrt b$ in general

Comment: Why simplify the expression if it's already simple? :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$x^2 = 4 + 2\sqrt{2} \rightarrow x = \pm \sqrt{4 + 2\sqrt{2}}$